# cdk command not found on MacOs

Tags: node.js, macos, aws-cdk

I was trying to install `aws-cdk` on my Mac, it was installed successfully via `npm install -g aws-cdk` version `1.85.0`. But then when I was trying to verify the installation with `cdk --version` I got the error `bash: cdk: command not found`. According to AWS documentation, `aws-cdk` is not compatible with Node.js version 13.0.0 to 13.6.0, but I got `v14.15.4`. How this can be fixed?

Comment: can you add the output of `npm list -g aws-cdk` and `which node`?

Comment: @alex9311, node is 14.5.4 and cdk is 1.85.0

Comment: P.S. /usr/local/bin/node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve it but didn't found the reason.
It was solved by adding an alias to .bash_profile as

```
# Setting path to aws cdk
alias cdk="/Users/andreyshedko/.npm-global/bin/bin/cdk"
```

Answer (score 0):

this sounds like the node/npm version(s?) on your machine are in a bad state somehow. I'd recommend following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x) on doing a full re-install for nodejs on your mac and reinstalling cdk if you haven't yet

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I was completely removed Node.js but this doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on my **mac air m1 2020**.
Open the *.zprofile* file in vscode and paste:

```
# Setting path to aws cdk
alias cdk="./.npm-global/bin/cdk"
```